# How to use Automapper to ProjectTo child entity

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper

I have the following entity classes

```
public class Customer
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [StringLength(254)]
    public string? Email { get; set; }
    public List<Order> Orders { get; set; } = new List<Order>();
}

public class Order
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long CustomerId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(CustomerId))]
    public Customer? Customer { get; set; }
    public DateOnly Date { get; set; }
    public List<OrderLine> Lines { get; set; } = [];
}

public class OrderLine
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long OrderId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(OrderId))]
    public Order? Order { get; set; }
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Item { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

And, there are corresponding data transfer objects (DTO):

```
public class CustomerDto
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

public class OrderDto
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long CustomerId { get; set; }
    public CustomerDto? Customer { get; set; }
    public DateOnly Date { get; set; }
    public List<OrderLineDto> Lines { get; set; } = [];
}

public class OrderLineDto
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long OrderId { get; set; }
    public string Item { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

I made the following AutoMapper configuration:

```
public class AutoMapperProfile : Profile
{
    public AutoMapperProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Customer, CustomerDto>()
            .ReverseMap()
            .ForPath(o => o.Id, o => o.Ignore());
        CreateMap<Order, OrderDto>()
            .ReverseMap()
            .ForPath(o => o.Id, o => o.Ignore());
        CreateMap<OrderLine, OrderLineDto>()
            .ReverseMap()
            .ForPath(o => o.Id, o => o.Ignore());
    }
}
```

The above configuration is registered to DI of my ASP.NET web application:

```
services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(AutoMapperProfile));
```

Now, I'd like to search Orders entity with specific search criteria and map it to OrderDto and send to my web client. For that I do the following:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateProjection<Order, OrderDto>());
IQueryable<Order> query = db.Orders
    .Include(o => o.Customer)
    .Include(o => o.Lines);

// Apply some Where criteria here

var orderDtos = await query
    .AsNoTracking()
    .OrderBy(o => o.Id)
    .ProjectTo<OrderDto>(config)
    .ToListAsync();
```

However, I got the following error:

```
Unable to create a map expression from Order.Customer to CustomerDto.Customer ...
```

I guess similar issue exists for OrderLineDto even though error message doesn't tell anything about it yet. I can I solve the issue? It looks like I should edit my configuration with ForMember method, but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: `var config = new MapperConfiguration(...)` does not use the registered configuration. Instead, you should inject `IMapper` and pass `mapper.Configuration` to `ProjectTo`.

Comment: Or call `mapper.ProjectTo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initialization of your mapping config is a bit suspect. If you are using an Automapper Profile, try this:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddProfile(new AutoMapperProfile());
var orderDtos = await db.Orders
    .OrderBy(o => o.Id)
    .ProjectTo<OrderDto>(config)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Note that when using projection you do not need to eager load related entities (`Include`) or worry about tracking. (`AsNoTracking`). No entities are populated or tracked, and EF will join the necessary tables automatically based on the mapped projections.

Comment: Yes, but as Ivan Stoev said above, he should use the injected mapper.

Comment: The answer is technically correct, but as Ivan Stoev and Lucian Bargaoanu pointed out, I should use injected mapper from DI: `.ProjectTo<OrderDto>(mapper.ConfigurationProvider)`